# How to do filter twice at different time ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Am trying to implement overlay twice but at different position and different time
Here is what am trying to do:
i just duplicate the filter

```
ffmpeg -t 50 -y -i film.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i gif.gif -filter_complex "


[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=1,scale=iw*2:-1[a];[0][a]overlay=x='200':y='300':shortest=1:enable='between(t,0,10)';

[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=1,scale=iw*2:-1[b];[0][b]overlay=x='200':y='300':shortest=1:enable='between(t,15,20)'"  

-acodec copy output_task_3.mp4
```

But only the first overlay is been implemented, the seconds is not!

how to archive this?

Now i wrote a PHP script that dose this filter once each time, and repeat proccess then merge all videos, but this is taking so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to double filter. You can extend the enable expression.

`enable='between(t,0,10)+between(t,15,20)'`

Comment: Thank you, but what if i want to also change position for each time?
For example:
First time x=100y=100
Second time x=350;y=505

Comment: Use expressions for x and y, e.g. for x:  `x='between(t,0,10)*100+between(t,15,20)*350'`

Comment: Thank you, it will be better to add this comment to the answer. Many thanks